# use a thread to wait 20 sec before doing action java android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

hello im trying to use thread to make a shooting system work
in order to work there is a button for a spacial attack and he can be used every 20 sec
i tried to follwing code to do so:

```
        ballatack.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonof);
        Thread timer2 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                ballatack.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonof);

            }
            }
        };
        timer2.start();
```

but it doesnt work , eclipse says nothing like verythings is right but when i run the emulator it doesnt work

Comment: define `it doesnt work` ... i think you're getting exception connected to running UI stuff on other thread ...

Comment: try `Thread.sleep(5000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot touch UI elements from other than the main thread . Try using a handler instead

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

ballatack.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonof);

mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ballatack.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonof);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't interact with UI elements in non-UI thread. Use Handler and its postDelayed method to set image on UI thread

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
ballatack.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
        ballatack.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonof);
   }
}, 5000);
```

That way you don't create a blocked thread and only interact with the UI elements on the UI thread.

Comment: nice! I forgot that UI elements also can use postDelayed method on their own

Comment: internally that is called the handler that the View already have. It's a very convenient way to do it.